# "Type expected" On Declaration Of Web Service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2013, reference, wsdl

I am writing an app in VS2013 (VB) to replace our site's text editor, TXTextControl from v16 to their new HTML5 editor v22.  I did not write the original code, but I have a tight release deadline so I'm trying to duplicate the original project as closely as possible, from the original code.  We already have a web service written in VS2010 (VB) to fill merge codes with data from our database.  I have deleted and re-added the web service multiple times, tried both a Service Reference and a Web Reference, deleted the reference and cleaned the project, etc.  I still am getting a "Type Expected" area when I try to dimension an object of the web service class.  Here is that code (subbing 'asdf' for my actual domain):

Dim document As com.asdf.cms.service.FileManager.FileManager = New com.asdf.cms.service.FileManager.FileManager()

I have a project setting, web service type, application scope, named BrowserControlApp_com_asdf_cms_service_FileManager_FileManager, which has a value of http://ws.staging.asdf.com/Services/FileManager/.

The following is in my web.config file:

```
  <applicationSettings>
    <BrowserControlApp.My.MySettings>
      <setting name="BrowserControlApp_com_asdf_cms_service_FileManager_FileManager"
        serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://ws.staging.asdf.com/Services/FileManager/</value>
      </setting>
    </BrowserControlApp.My.MySettings>
  </applicationSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="FileManagerSoap" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://ws.staging.asdf.com/Services/FileManager/FileManager.asmx"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="FileManagerSoap"
        contract="com.asdf.cms.service.FileManager.FileManager.FileManagerSoap"
        name="FileManagerSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

One strange thing I noticed is that the wsdl file contains two completely different locations for the service - one of which, while visually similar to the actual service URL is not even a valid URL for 
the service as seen in the following snippet:

```
    <wsdl:operation name="LoadEnvelope">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://asdf.com/cms/services/filemanager/LoadEnvelope" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="FileManager">
    <wsdl:port name="FileManagerSoap" binding="tns:FileManagerSoap">
      <soap:address location="http://ws.staging.asdf.com/Services/FileManager/FileManager.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="FileManagerSoap12" binding="tns:FileManagerSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="http://ws.staging.asdf.com/Services/FileManager/FileManager.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
```

I believe I've provided all the pertinent information.  Can anyone see why my service type is not resolving?  Thanks in advance, and any help is appreciated!

```
Thanks,
Mike
```

Comment: I've changed all the web service URIs to the proper value, but still no joy.  I also unchecked "Reuse Type Assemblies" on the Configure Service dialog, which has been an issue in the past.  Still no joy.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but before I started having issues I changed the project name and main page from WebApplication2 to BrowserControlApp. Looking in the obj/debug folder (which, along with the bin folder I just had to include in the project) I see all files are still named WebApplication2.

Comment: Additionally, the SiteMaster file and files in the Account folder still have references to WebApplication2, but I am not using those - at least not explicitly.